# Is it possible to protect single procedure with multiple security test in Adapters IBM Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

I am creating app and I have added Android, Mobile webapp as an Worklight Environment that means I want to use same App as webapp(by using its URL). I am creating 2 seperate security test one is Mobile security test and other one is Web security test, but my Adapters procedure are common(for eg:procedure1), **So is it possible to apply two security test to one single procedure.**This is what I tried but it didn't worked.

Following is my Mobile security Test

```
    <mobileSecurityTest name="BankingTest">
        <testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
        <testUser realm="BankingRealm" />
        <testDirectUpdate mode="perSession" />
    </mobileSecurityTest>
```

Following is my Web security Test

```
    <webSecurityTest name="BankingWebTest">
        <testUser realm="BankingWebRealm"/>
    </webSecurityTest>
```

Following is how procedure is protected in xml file

```
<procedure name="getDetail" securityTest="BankingTest"/>(Its working).
```

But when I tried

```
    <procedure name="getDetail" securityTest="BankingTest"/>
   <procedure name="getDetail" securityTest="BankingWebTest"/>
                   --OR--
<procedure name="getDetail" securityTest="BankingWebTest;BankingTest"/>
```

its not working.

My requirement is: I want to protect 1 same procedure with 2 different security test. So Please suggest me what is better approach and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you need a separate realm for web and mobile.

Additionally, you cannot set more than one securityTest per procedure.

Consider not using two realms if not required and then use a custom securityTest instead of one for web and one for mobile.

Comment: Thnx Idan for ur answer, but if I use only Mobile security Test for both Web and Mobile as webSecurityTest contains wl_anonymousUserRealm and wl_antiXSRFRealm by default and mobileSecurityTest contains wl_anonymousUserRealm, wl_antiXSRFRealm, wl_remoteDisableRealm, wl_directUpdateRealm and wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm by default. will it work, instead of creating our custom SecurityTest

Comment: You need to ask yourself what are you trying to protect (adapter or client), and why do you think you need 2 security tests to achieve it). From the question and the above comment, the scenario is not clear to me. So I cannot comment further.

Comment: thnx again Idan, I am clear I got my answer my major concern was that can I create two security test for one procedure which u answered.

Comment: @Idan-I have common adapters and resources for both mobile and webapp so how to protect them when they(procedures of adapters) called from their respective environments say I call procedure from my webapp and it is protected with mobileSecurity test, will it affect web channel .

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that you can use more than one securityTest to protect the same procedure or resource.

Comment: You can use only 1 securityTest per adapter procedure.

Comment: Right. I missed the "don't". :-)